# Emberjs: updating belongsTo doesn't send id to the API

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to update a model's belongsTo relation but Ember doesn't send the `category_id` attribute to the API unless I set async to false which I don't want.

Here are my models:

```
App.reopen
  Category: DS.Model.extend(
    name: DS.attr('string')
  )
  Product: DS.Model.extend(
    category: DS.belongsTo('category', async: true)
  )
```

And here a similar example of how I try to update a product.

```
@store.find('category', 1).then (category) ->
  product.set('category', category)
  product.save()
```

When looking into the logs of my API there is no `category_id` attribute given. If I remove `async: true` from my model definition everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by upgrading ember-data to `1.0.0.beta.12`